# Turning user email into a configurable field

Tags: 8, entities

I am using drupal 8 and am running into an issue with the field entity_field:user:mail. This field is available on users, but not visible to users other than Administrator and the user itself, or usable in views or the display. I can access it through Panelizer, but again, nobody but Administrator has access to view it. I want to display it on the user profile page (which I created using panelizer), so all I really need is to be able to set the permissions for the field. Since it's only a base field, the https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions module doesn't help either.

Does anybody have a clue how to make the field configurable? I was looking at the API docs on https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/defining-and-using-content-entity-field-definitions but it's hard to see the forest through the trees there.

Any pointers as to how I can either do this with an existing module/configuration (probably not) or which hook I need to look at to modify the field to become a configurable field? If I need to create a module for it, it's fine, but if I can do it on the theme level, it would be better (already have a custom theme anyway).